# iniciar app automaticamente a una hora especifica

Tags: java, android, android-studio

soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo movil, estoy desarrollando una app en la cual un requisito es que esta se inicie en una hora dada ya he probado con la funcionalidad del android alarm manager

```
 public void alarma(){
    String cadena="14:28:00";
    int hora,minute,seg;
    hora = Integer.parseInt(cadena.substring(0,2));
    // minute = Integer.parseInt(cadena.substring(3,5));
    seg = Integer.parseInt(cadena.substring(6,8));

    if(Integer.parseInt(cadena.substring(3,5)) < 59)
        minute = Integer.parseInt(cadena.substring(3,5)) + 1;
    else
        minute = Integer.parseInt(cadena.substring(3,5));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyappReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PackageManager pm = (PackageManager)getPackageManager();

    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    //pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

**y este es my broadcast**

```
public class MyappReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

   Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   context.startActivity(i);
}
```

}

pero no inicia en android 10, cualquier sugerencia estare eternamente agradecido

Answer (score 3):

Te paso una app que genera una alarma a los 50 segundos de presionar un botón

Puedes ir jugando con ella e ir cambiando esos segundos por la hora a la que deseas que se ejecute tu aplicación.

Lo que hace ésta, es abrir una segunda pantalla. El código lo encontré hace tiempo por internet y lo adapté para para mis necesidades, aquí se abrirá una segunda actícity

El código de es la aplicación completa, o sea, si la copias entera tal como te la pongo, te funcionará, lo que deberías es de añadir las activities completas a tu aplicación y en el main pegar el código y la estructura

En tu caso deberías de sustituir el código de apertura de la segunda activity por el de abrir tu aplicación

Espero pueda servirte de ayuda

Crea una clase AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //------< onReceive() >--------
        //Al saltar la alarma en el timepo programado se abre la pantalla
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, PaginaAlarma.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //open Activitiy
        context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
        //------</ onReceive() >--------
    }
}
```

Creas ahora la clase BackgroundSoundService que extienda de Service:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    
    //crea el tag de un servicio en segundo plano
    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
    private AlarmManager alarmManager  = null;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent  = null;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service started...");
    }
    //método de inicio
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
        return null;
    }
    //método de parada
    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
    }
    //método de pausa
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
    }
    //método de destrucción de la actividad
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
}
```

En el MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private AlarmManager alarmManager  = null;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent  = null;
    BackgroundSoundService miServicio = new BackgroundSoundService();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    //========< Buttons >===========
    public void btnOpenWakeup(View view) {
        Intent openWakeup = new Intent(this, PaginaAlarma.class);
        startActivity(openWakeup);
    }
    public void btnAlarmSetWakeup(View view) {
        //--------< btnAlarmSetWakeup() >--------
        setupAlarm();
        //--------</ btnAlarmSetWakeup() >--------
    }
    //========</ Buttons >===========


    //========< Methods >===========

    private void setupAlarm() {
        //--------< setupAlarm() >--------
        // AlarmManager instance from the system services
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)   this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Intent: this is responsible to prepare the android component what
        //PendingIntent will start when the alarm is triggered. That component 
        //can be anyone    (activity, service, broadcastReceiver, etc)
        // Intent to start the Broadcast Receiver
        Intent intent =new  Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        // PendingIntent: this is the pending intent, which waits until 
        //the right time, to be called by AlarmManager
        // The Pending Intent to pass in AlarmManager
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        //< create Alarm >
        setAlarm();
        //</ create Alarm >
        //--------</ setupAlarm() >--------
    }

    private void setAlarm() {
        //--------< setup() >--------
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) is.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //en ésta parte tenemos declarado el tiempo de retardo para que salte la alarma, en éste caso 50.000 milisegundos, 50 segundos
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 50000, endingIntent);
        //--------</ setup() >--------
    }
    //========</ Methods >===========
    //------------</ MainActivity >------------
 }
```

Creas ahora la página de Alarma:

```
 public class PaginaAlarma extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina_alarma);
    }
}
```

XML Main Activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOpenWakeup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#A1A0A0"

    android:onClick="btnOpenWakeup"
    android:text="Open Wakeup"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnWakeup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFEB3B"
    android:onClick="btnAlarmSetWakeup"
    android:text="Alarm: Wakeup"
    android:textColor="#F44336"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnOpenWakeup" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

pagina XML de Alarma:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    tools:context=".PaginaAlarma">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alarm"
    android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte estimado, pero una consulta, te funciona en android 10?, lo ejecute y no se inicia, no pasa nada

Comment: Mantienes la aplicación abierta mientras esperas ?. ahora me pillas en cuánto a la versión que utilizaba, pero creo recordar que si que me funcionaba en la 10.

Comment: emmm no la aplicacion puede estar cerrada, completamente

Comment: Cerrando la aplicación, a mí también me daba problemas. Funcionaba estando en segundo plano. Estuve mucho tiempo buscando una solución para eso, y ésta fue la más aproximada. Mi intención era para una reserva en una fecha y hora concreta. Lo que hacía la aplicación era avisar 15 minutos antes de finalizar el tiempo disponible. Pero si desde la fecha de la reserva hasta el día de la misma se cerraba la aplicación, no se producía el aviso por el evento de alarma.

Comment: la cosa es que con la aplicacion en segundo plano, o cerrada completamente no logro hacer que la app se inicie, o al menos que logre abrir una activity, estoy abrumado ya no se que hacer, estuve modificando tu codigo para ver si lo hacia funcionar y nada

Comment: Pues ya lo siento. Espero tengas mas uerte que yo, pues en mi caso lo habia dejado por imposible. Un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias, si encuentro una solucion lo compartire por acá, saludos ten buen dia

Comment: Esto no realiza lo que pregunta el OP "iniciar app automáticamente a una hora especifica" , revisa [answer] ,saludos.